# Analysing a Thread dump using java

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, java-threads, thread-synchronization

I have a thread dump. Now, I want to know how many threads are running, what is their run time, what is its current state.
I don't want to use third party tools. I need a java code which takes dump file as input and shows the o/p.The main purpose is to find how long the threads were waiting.I want to find the threads with longest wait time!!

Answer (score 2):

Use **jvisualvm**.It comes with your JDK.

[image]

Comment: After Loading the thread dump file , its just showing all threads with thread id,priority,nid,state .But I want the execution time. Atleast I need when it has been created .

Comment: The main purpose is to find how long the threads were waiting.I want to find the threads with longest wait time!!

Comment: Sorry, but if it isn't showing that information I don't know how to get it.